# Javascript cannot set innerHTML of button with id because it's "null"

Tags: javascript, html, css, null

My goal is to have a button that onclick will call a function to change the styling of the html tag and the text (or innerHTML) of the button itself. Shouldn't be that hard, right? Well...

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>New look for my site!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <script src="change-template.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <aside>
    <button type="button" id="template-button" onclick="changeTemplate()">Nightmode: On</button>
  </aside>
  <main>
    <h1>New page look for my site</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS (main.css):

```
html{
  background: "#111";
  color: "#0F0";
}
```

JS (change-template.js):

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
var button = document.getElementById('template-button');
var nightmode = true;

function changeTemplate(){
  //change to lighter color if black and vice versa
  if(nightmode){
    html.style.background = "#EEE";
    html.style.color = "#000";
    button.innerHTML = "Nightmode: OFF";
  }else{
    html.style.background = "#111";
    html.style.color = "#0F0";
    button.innerHTML = "Nightmode: ON";
  }
  nightmode = !nightmode;
}
```

And I'm getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
>       at changeTemplate (change-template.js:10)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (new-look.html:11)

So please help me it's 90 degrees and I'm sitting here on the verge of hunger stressed about this simple issue and can barely think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because, your script is parsed, event before the elements are available in the `DOM`.

When the parser encounters `var button = document.getElementById('template-button');` the element is not yet available in the `DOM`.

Because of which your code is technically doing this.

`undefined.innerHTML`

Move the script tag to just above the closing body tag. This will fix the issue since the elements are available in the `DOM`, when they get stored in the variables.

```
 </main>
  <script src="change-template.js"></script>
</body>
```

if you still want to include your script in the head, the other way around is wrap the code in `document.onload` which triggers, when the DOM is ready.

```
document.onload = function(e) { 
    // your code goes here
};
```

Comment: Sir/ma'am, you have saved me from going insane. I feel like a fool forgetting this. It's like `function functionName(){}` in javascript, it can be called even before the definition, but `var function = function(){}` cannot. So I'm not used to this order. I'm going to go eat now.